# How to play an animated gif (or a video) on the background of a layout?

Tags: android, animation, layout, video, gif

In my spare time I'm learning android. I want to create a layout with a background image which includes an animation. 
I know how to use `linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.BlaBla)` but if I place a gif image it becomes a static image but not animated. Also, I'm not sure if I can play a video on it. Can anyone post a simple code or just give the directions about that if possible? Minsdk version will be 8 (2.2).

*PS*: I know I can use media to play videos using `VideoView` but it's not a layout, therefore, I can't add some views on it. Please don't suggest that.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835060/android-mediaplayer-how-to-use-surfaceview-or-mediaplayer-to-play-video-in-cor

Comment: thanks mate but it's not the think I wanted :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just use gif.

Maybe this will help if you want to animate something:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

With video, I think you should not just put it in background but use media player and then perhaps have some layouts on top if you want to overlay it with some info.

Hope this helped.

Comment: "_With video, I think you should not just put it in background but use media player and then perhaps have some layouts on top if you want to overlay it with some info._" Yeah, that's trick I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a webView,  I've never tested that:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);                   
myWebView.loadUrl("http://img.gif");
```