# While converting byte[] array to String got exception in android

Tags: android

```
float rotation =getRotatedImage(imgdata);
```

//Where imgdata is the String which is require on method getRotatedImage(imgdata).

//My own method to get the oreintation of picture

```
private float getRotatedImage(String imgdata2) {
         try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imgdata2);
            int rotation = (int)exifOrientationToDegrees(
                    exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL));
            return rotation;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("CAMERA IMAGE", "Error checking exif", e);
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0f;
    }
```

// inside on picture taken i am converting the byte data to String

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        Log.i("CAMERA", "ON PICTURE TAKEN");
        int length = arg0.length;
        if (length != 0) {

            //bitimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);

            finalimage = arg0;
            if(finalimage!=null)
            {
                imgdata=converttostring(finalimage);
            }
            //compressimageforshow();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IMAGE PROCESSING DONE", 0)
                    .show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO IMAGE ", 0).show();
        }
        arg1.startPreview();
        //shutterButton.setEnabled(false);
        show_image_bt.setEnabled(true);

    }
```

//Here my method in order to convert to string

```
private String converttostring(byte[] finalimage2) {
        // String basestr=Base64.encodeToString(finalimage2, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        return new String(finalimage2);

    }
```

//Here is my logcat exception details:

```
01-22 18:06:48.808: I/ACTIVITY(344): ON CREATE
01-22 18:06:48.808: I/ACTIVITY(344): ON RESUME
01-22 18:06:49.348: I/CAMERA(344): ON SURFACE CHANGE
01-22 18:06:53.018: I/CAMERA(344): ON PICTURE TAKEN
01-22 18:06:56.188: E/(344): can't open '������JFIF����`��`��������fExif����II*������������������>��������������F������(��������������1��������N��������������`������������`������������Paint.NET v3.36������C��
01-22 18:06:56.188: E/(344): 
01-22 18:06:56.188: E/(344): 
01-22 18:06:56.188: E/(344): 

����C       

�������@"�������������������������� 
01-22 18:06:56.188: E/(344): �����������}��!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�  
01-22 18:06:56.188: E/(344): %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������   
01-22 18:06:56.188: E/(344): ���������w��!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�
01-22 18:06:56.188: E/(344): $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�����������������
```

//so please can anyone tell me what to do also tried the Base64 of android class

```
imgdata=Base64.encodeToString(finalimage,Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

where imgdata is string ,finalimage is the byte array.

Waiting for reply.Please forgive me for my language and coding style.

//Here i am mentioning the button click event for which the exception is generating

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
case R.id.show_image:
            show_image_imgvw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            retake_photo_bt.setEnabled(true);
            show_image_bt.setEnabled(false);
            preview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (finalimage != null) {
                resizeimageforshow();
                show_image_imgvw.setImageBitmap(bitimage);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IMAGE DISPLAYED", 0)
                        .show();
```

on click of this button exception is generating.
// inside the resizeimagefroshow() calling  the getRotatedimage() and after that creating new bitmap 
image for display

//code here:

```
private void resizeimageforshow() {
        if (finalimage != null) {
            // bitimage=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(finalimage, 0,
            // finalimage.length);
            // show_image_imgvw.setImageBitmap(bitimage);
            Bitmap myimage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(finalimage, 0,
                    finalimage.length);
            // imgdata=Base64.encodeToString(finalimage,Base64.NO_WRAP);
            android.graphics.Matrix matrix = new android.graphics.Matrix();
            float rotation = getRotatedImage(imgdata);
            if (rotation != 0f) {
                matrix.preRotate(rotation);
            }
            bitimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(myimage1, 0, 0, myimage1.getWidth(),
                    myimage1.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: If you change  imgdata=converttostring(finalimage); to  imgdata= new String(finalimage); do you get the error?

Comment: `return new String(finalimage2);` this doesn't make sense. you cannot convert a byte[] representing an image directly into a String

Comment: the Base64 version makes much more sense

Comment: also, testing `if(finalimage!=null)` is useless, as you access `arg0.length` a few lines before (finalimage == null => arg0 == null => arg0.length throws NPE)

Comment: what i don't understand is where do you get the can't open JFIF error ?

Comment: in the logcat section while running the application.

Comment: i had button to show the capture image

Comment: @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  switch (arg0.getId()) {

Answer (score 0):

As @njzk2 mentioned you are converting binary image data into string doesn't make any sense. What you want is a filename string to pass into `ExifInterface` constructor.

So first you must save the image data into a file:

```
File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "camera_picture.jpg");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file.toString());
try {
    os.write(finalimage);
} finally {
    os.close();
}
```

Then you can use `ExifInterface` with the `filename`.

If you want to read the metadata directly from a stream you'll have to use third party library. See [reading android jpeg EXIF metadata from picture callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944123/reading-android-jpeg-exif-metadata-from-picture-callback).

Comment: I can't save the file directly after capturing because i had to put some color or effect to the picture.

Comment: Secondly my objective is to take the image in portrait mode with the samsung and picture should appear as it look