# Download Image and retain Exif data on android

Tags: java, android, exif

Currently I am trying to download an Image from a Webserver and retain the Exif data which are attached to the picture. Downloading the image itself is no problem at all. Example Code is like this (without any try/catch or AsyncTask related code to make it readable)

```
final HttpGet request = new HttpGet("IMAGE_URL");
final AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");

HttpResponse response   = httpClient.execute(request);
InputStream inputStream = inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Now I simply would call the **BitmapFactory** to create a Bitmap object from the Inputstream like this

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

First I thought the BitmapFactory is the culprit and tried to read the Exif data from a file created from the inputstream. The ExifInterface can't get the Exif data and opened on Windows the saved image has no Exif at all.

Answer (score 1):

Android Api won't allow you to read `exif` data from a `Stream`, only from a `File`. For more
info you can use this link : [Reading android jpeg EXIF metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944123/reading-android-jpeg-exif-metadata-from-picture-callback)

Download metadata extractor from the link given [Click Here](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/downloads/list) to download the library choose the version **2.5.0.RC-3.zip**

Extract the jar Folder and import jar into libs folder in your poject and then execute the below code

```
try 
{
    InputStream is = new URL("your image url").openStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(bis,true);

    for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) 
    {
        for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) 
        {
            System.out.println(tag);
        }
    }
}
catch (ImageProcessingException e){}
catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: I already tried to use a newer version of this library, but my project wasn't building anymore so I skipped this solution. Maybe I give it another shot with this version.

Comment: Works well still in 2023. The library is updated yearly.