# GPS tagged captured images in android

Tags: android, image, gps

I have captured a picture using the phone camera and stored it in variable "photo"

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

I have also obtained the latitude and longitude using the phone gps

```
lat = location.getLatitude();
lon = location.getLongitude();
```

How do I incorporate this gps data in the image only?

P.S. GPS tagged images can be captured manually by enabling the GPS tag option in the camera settings by the user. I want to make sure that the image captured is compulsorily GPS tagged.

Comment: this might be helpful for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12952370/508126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't set it to the Bitmap, the Bitmap is just a byte array with the image pixels.
You have to apply those coordinates after you save it to a file that supports Metadata (for example PNG or JPG)

To do that you use the [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)

Code is similar to that:

```
String filePath = Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp/photo.png";
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

// call this next setAttributes a few times to write all the GPS data to it.
exif.setAttribute(... );

// don't forget to save
exif.saveAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/495285/Android/Mobile/Capturing-GPS-Coordinates-Picture-Design) the what you are looking for?