# Get android device orientation even when autoRotation is turned off

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-orientation

I have an android app in which the screen orientation is set to portrait in manifest file.
It uses a custom camera in b/w , to take a photo and I need to save the photo.

Before I save the image I have to rotate the image depending on how the user is holding the camera, so that the image gets saved in the right orientation.

So, is there any way by which I can get the device orientation even when my app is running in portrait mode and android "auto-rotation" feature is ON.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using android orientation sensor to solve this problem and its working perfectly. Till someone gives a better working method , am accepting this as answer for other who have the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You should do the rotation depending on the orientation information within the image, not depending on the device orientation.

[Here is some more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944123/reading-android-jpeg-exif-metadata-from-picture-callback) on how to determine the rotation.

Since this does not help, have you tried hackpod's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone):

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Comment: I get the byte[] in  onPictureCallBack() , from there how can I see the orientation information?

Comment: I added a link to the SO question I followed.

Comment: just tried it, the Exif Meta data is also having the orientation as 1 always

Comment: yes I have tried that one too.not working. Finally now am using an orientaion sensor to get the value , which is not the optimal solution for my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't help you :-(

Answer (score 1):

To get current device orientation try this:

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

Comment: This gives me my activity windows orientation. I have set it to portrait always

Answer (score 0):

Simply check, the height and width of the image. If the height is less than your width, it means the user was holding the phone horizontally, so you have to rotate it.

Comment: both times the width and height will be same , as the camera is working in portrait mode only. I checked now.