# I want to read exif info in image in android. I can read exif from image in gallery but i cannot read exif photo taken from the camera

Tags: android, camera, gps, metadata, exif

[image: Example image]

As shown in the figure above.I chose the take a picture exif information is null. I chose image from phone option and exif information is not null.

Comment: Can you provide what logic you are using?

Comment: Please can you share ,how you are even getting the exit data , and how many kind of exit data we can get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read exif data from a Stream using the android api. ExifInterface doesn't have a constructor with an InputStream.

However, You can use the  [metadata-extractor](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/)
and use the constructor with an InputStream to build an InputStream backed by your byte[] using a ByteArrayInputStream

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to read EXIF data from streams through the ExifInterface Support Library.

```
compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:25.1.0"
```

Source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html

Answer (score 1):

Android API do not read EXIF from `Stream`.

Check this one -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12952370/842607