# Playing video using MediaPlayer class

Tags: android, video, media-player

I am trying to make use of `MediaPlayer` class for playing a video file. The problem is video is not getting displayed at all though I can hear the sound in the video playing.

Following is the code of activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private SurfaceView surfaceView;
private Button btnPlay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    addListener();

}

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
}

private void addListener() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
}

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnPlay:
        try{
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }else{
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wildlife);
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(176, 144);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mediaPlayer.start();}
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
  }
   }
```

Following is the code of layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/surfaceView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/surfaceView1"
    android:text="@string/play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

please tell me what needs to be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your own surface view and call this surface view in your activity to play the video. Hope this may solve your problem

Comment: I stumbled upon this question while trying for myself, turns out I only needed to call setSurface method in and OnSurfaceAvailable callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `onSizeChanged()` function of the `SurfaceView` class to get and set the size of the view.

```
protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
```

When ever the screen size has changed, this class is called.

As a second alternative, you may be able to set the size by setting the layout parameters (unsure if this works with ScrollView):

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = this.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = 1000; // required width
    lp.height = 1000; // required height
    this.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set surface View height and width to fill parent in xml file.

```
  <SurfaceView
android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting your **SurfaceView layout to wrap_content** **will not size a video to play at the proper aspect ratio.**

You can refer to this answer link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6283676/1441666

And also this blog **[Play media on surfaceview using android.media.MediaPlayer](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/play-media-on-surfaceview-using.html)**

Comment: Yeah the link you provided was quiet helpful and the app in there was able to play same video file from SD card. But I don't want to use the `ContentProvider` i.e. `MediaStore`. so can you suggest me a link from where I can check how to make use of raw resource to play video using `MediaPlayer` class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if you need an specific situation, but have you already tried [FullscreenVideoView](https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView)?

It tries to abstracts all those SurfaceView problems and you can focus only in UI buttons. As It's open, you can subclass FullscreenVideoView and customize as you need.